# Inherit from a Singleton and a base class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my Unity game, I have one player and one enemy (it's a card game so this is always true).
I use a basic Singleton base class to access them from any sub-system in the game, like this:

```cs
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
{
    public static T instance;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        if (instance != null) {
            string typename = typeof(T).Name;
            Debug.LogWarning($"More that one instance of {typename} found.");
        }
        instance = this as T;
    }
}

public class Player : Singleton<Player>
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

public class Enemy : Singleton<Enemy>
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

public class OtherPartOfGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start() {
        Player.instance.DoSomething();
        Enemy.instance.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

But I want to pull out some common functionality into a base class CharacterBase.
Of course normally I'd just do this:

```cs
public abstract class CharacterBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}

public class Player : CharacterBase
{
    public override void DoSomething() {}
}

public class Enemy : CharacterBase
{
    public override void DoSomething() {}
}
```

But how do I also keep my generic Singleton in the mix, without using multiple inheritance?

Comment: `public abstract class Singleton<T, TMonoBehaviour> :  TMonoBehaviour where T : Component` ?

Comment: Note also as it currently stands only having an `abstract` method you could do the same using an `interface` (though I suspect you want to implement more into your `CharacterBase`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the easiest way would be to just let your `CharacterBase` class inherit from `Singleton` like this

```
public abstract class CharacterBase<T> : Singleton<T> where T : Component
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
}
```

and then do

```
public class Player : CharacterBase<Player>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}

public class Enemy : CharacterBase<Enemy>
{
    public override void DoSomething() { ... }
}
```

Everything else would just complicate it for no good reason.

Comment: It’s not different from your `Player : Singleton<Player>`... It’s now `Player : CharacterBase<Player>` instead.

Comment: Ahh got it that's cool!  And then `Player` derives from `CharacterBase<Player>`.  I get it!

Comment: Yep sorry I deleted my comment just as you responded.  Misread your code at first.

Comment: @ack you should probably accept this answer then ;)